# Where clause based on the current week

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

I have a sql table which has a date column (let say deployDate). Now I need to select data in this basis.

Let say user has selected 01-27-2012 (which is friday) so I need to filter my data for this week only (i.e. Sunday to Saturday -  01-22-2012 to  01-28-2012)

How to write where clause for this?

Comment: I would just use a standard date range, and figure out the start and end before i call the query.  I am guessing you are probably using C# (or something similar) which has a nice DateTime struct which is easier to use and understand than the calls in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where datepart(week, deployDate) = datepart(week, @selectedDeployDate)
```